# PHP: One select option to several arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, html-select

I just began PH and I have a problem that blocks me. I have a Select form and I need to associate each option to several arrays in a multidimensional array.
Here my select:

```
 <select name="city">
            <option value="Dublin">Dublin</option>
            <option value="Nice">Nice</option>
            <option value="Orleans">Orléans</option>
            <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
            <option value="Tours">Tours</option>
        </select>
```

And my multi array:

```
$travels = array(
          '0' => array('Départ ' =>'Paris', 'Arrivée ' => 'Nantes', 'Heure de départ ' => '11:00', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' => '12:34', 'Chauffeur ' => 'Thomas'),
          '1' => array('Départ ' =>'Orléans', 'Arrivée ' => 'Nantes', 'Heure de départ ' =>'05:15', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' => '09:32', 'Chauffeur ' =>'Mathieu'),
          '2' => array('Départ ' =>'Dublin', 'Arrivée ' => 'Tours', 'Heure de départ ' =>'07:23', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' => '08:50', 'Chauffeur ' =>'Nathanaël'),
          '3' => array('Départ ' =>'Paris', 'Arrivée ' => 'Orléans', 'Heure de départ ' =>'03:00', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' => '05:26', 'Chauffeur ' => 'Clément'),
          '4' => array('Départ ' =>'Paris', 'Arrivée ' => 'Nice', 'Heure de départ ' => '10:00', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' => '12:09', 'Chauffeur ' => 'Audrey'),
          '5' => array('Départ ' =>'Nice', 'Arrivée ' => 'Nantes', 'Heure de départ ' => '10:40', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' =>'13:00', 'Chauffeur ' =>'Pollux'),
          '6' => array('Départ ' =>'Nice', 'Arrivée ' => 'Tours', 'Heure de départ ' => '11:00', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' => '16:10', 'Chauffeur ' =>'Edouard'),
          '7' => array('Départ ' =>'Tours', 'Arrivée ' => 'Amboise', 'Heure de départ ' => '16:00', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' => '18:40', 'Chauffeur ' =>'Priscilla'),
          '8' => array('Départ ' =>'Nice', 'Arrivée ' => 'Nantes', 'Heure de départ ' => '12:00', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' =>'16:00', 'Chauffeur ' =>'Charlotte'),
```

The problem is I need to display the arrays in which the "Départ" value correspond to the select option.

To be more precise, if I select "Paris", the arrays (and all the values) 0, 3 and 4 will display.
For the moment I only know how to display all the arrays (even those I don't need).

I don't know if I was clear enough.
Thank you by advance for all your helps.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way to do this, but this quick snippet can help with what you are trying to achieve:

```
<?php
     $travels = array(
      '0' => array('Départ ' =>'Paris', 'Arrivée ' => 'Nantes', 'Heure de départ ' => '11:00', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' => '12:34', 'Chauffeur ' => 'Thomas'),
      '1' => array('Départ ' =>'Orléans', 'Arrivée ' => 'Nantes', 'Heure de départ ' =>'05:15', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' => '09:32', 'Chauffeur ' =>'Mathieu'),
      '2' => array('Départ ' =>'Dublin', 'Arrivée ' => 'Tours', 'Heure de départ ' =>'07:23', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' => '08:50', 'Chauffeur ' =>'Nathanaël'),
      '3' => array('Départ ' =>'Paris', 'Arrivée ' => 'Orléans', 'Heure de départ ' =>'03:00', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' => '05:26', 'Chauffeur ' => 'Clément'),
      '4' => array('Départ ' =>'Paris', 'Arrivée ' => 'Nice', 'Heure de départ ' => '10:00', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' => '12:09', 'Chauffeur ' => 'Audrey'),
      '5' => array('Départ ' =>'Nice', 'Arrivée ' => 'Nantes', 'Heure de départ ' => '10:40', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' =>'13:00', 'Chauffeur ' =>'Pollux'),
      '6' => array('Départ ' =>'Nice', 'Arrivée ' => 'Tours', 'Heure de départ ' => '11:00', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' => '16:10', 'Chauffeur ' =>'Edouard'),
      '7' => array('Départ ' =>'Tours', 'Arrivée ' => 'Amboise', 'Heure de départ ' => '16:00', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' => '18:40', 'Chauffeur ' =>'Priscilla'),
      '8' => array('Départ ' =>'Nice', 'Arrivée ' => 'Nantes', 'Heure de départ ' => '12:00', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' =>'16:00', 'Chauffeur ' =>'Charlotte'));


// get your select option (assuming Orléans)
$selectOption = "Orléans";

$temp = array();

foreach ($travels as $key => $value) {

    $t = $travels[$key]['Départ '];

    if ($t == $selectOption) {
        array_push($temp, $value);
    }
}

print_r($temp);
```

I'd advise you find a way to store the result of **temp** for a given selection to avoid recomputing over and over again.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know we could write $travels[$key]['Départ '] , so that's why I was stuck.

Comment: Well this works fine since you're using a multidimensional array. So you'd in effect need two keys to access the value you want in this particular 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) method:

```
<?php

$travels = array(
          '0' => array('Départ ' =>'Paris', 'Arrivée ' => 'Nantes', 'Heure de départ ' => '11:00', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' => '12:34', 'Chauffeur ' => 'Thomas'),
          '1' => array('Départ ' =>'Orléans', 'Arrivée ' => 'Nantes', 'Heure de départ ' =>'05:15', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' => '09:32', 'Chauffeur ' =>'Mathieu'),
          '2' => array('Départ ' =>'Dublin', 'Arrivée ' => 'Tours', 'Heure de départ ' =>'07:23', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' => '08:50', 'Chauffeur ' =>'Nathanaël'),
          '3' => array('Départ ' =>'Paris', 'Arrivée ' => 'Orléans', 'Heure de départ ' =>'03:00', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' => '05:26', 'Chauffeur ' => 'Clément'),
          '4' => array('Départ ' =>'Paris', 'Arrivée ' => 'Nice', 'Heure de départ ' => '10:00', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' => '12:09', 'Chauffeur ' => 'Audrey'),
          '5' => array('Départ ' =>'Nice', 'Arrivée ' => 'Nantes', 'Heure de départ ' => '10:40', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' =>'13:00', 'Chauffeur ' =>'Pollux'),
          '6' => array('Départ ' =>'Nice', 'Arrivée ' => 'Tours', 'Heure de départ ' => '11:00', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' => '16:10', 'Chauffeur ' =>'Edouard'),
          '7' => array('Départ ' =>'Tours', 'Arrivée ' => 'Amboise', 'Heure de départ ' => '16:00', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' => '18:40', 'Chauffeur ' =>'Priscilla'),
          '8' => array('Départ ' =>'Nice', 'Arrivée ' => 'Nantes', 'Heure de départ ' => '12:00', 'Heure d\'arrivée ' =>'16:00', 'Chauffeur ' =>'Charlotte')
          );

$selected = 'Paris';

function get_destination($travel) {
    global $selected;

    return $travel["Départ "] === $selected;
}

print_r(array_filter($travels, 'get_destination'));
```